# Why don't we emphasize "length of input string" when considering time complexity of sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

The knapsack problem is $O(c\,n)$ where $c$ is the capacity of knapsack and $n$ is the number of items. Yet it's exponential because the size of the input is $\log(c)$.

However, why don't we emphasize length of input in other algorithms? To name one example, what would be the **input size $n$** and **worst case time complexity $T$** of the following input when using insertion sort:

`111111111,101,11,10,1,0`

Answer A: $n=6$, $T=O(n^2)$
Answer B: n = space(all_digits)+space(delimiters_between_numerics)

If B is correct, what is the time complexity $T$?

Comment: one way to visualize this. this is not taught/pointed out much in CS classes but theres a perfect proportional/inverse "tradeoff" between size of elements, number of elements, and total [memory] size of the input. for a fixed total memory size you can vary the # of elements to be less but then each one is larger and the total memory size is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that the input length of a Knapsack instance is $\Theta(n \cdot \log \max \{c,w_1,\dots,w_n\})$. Assuming the instance is "pruned", namely that all weights are at most $c$, this is $\Theta(n\log c)$.

In order to answer such questions, you need to fix

- the machine model,
- the [cost model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models),
- the set of valid inputs and
- the algorithm.

You don't give the first three.

So your question is not well defined. In order store this particular set of numbers on a Turing machine tape, six symbols are indeed sufficient (one per number), and then the algorithm would run in time $O(1)$ on its only input. In order to get a general algorithm, however, you need to "properly" encode the numbers, namely B is the correct answer. I'll assume the latter.

Insertion sort has worst-case complexity $\Theta(n^2)$ in the RAM model with uniform cost model (elementary operations on naturals cost $1$), $n$ being the number of elements. In particular, it is independent of the size of the numbers. Since $n \leq |i|$, $i$ the input, you get an $O(|i|^2)$ time algorithm.

If you apply the logarithmic cost model (elementar operations on naturals have cost depending on their encoding length, cf. elementary school), you get time $\Theta(n^2 \cdot \log E)$ with $E = \log \max\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ the length of the largest input number, because the $\Theta(n^2)$ comparisons on the elements dominate the runtime. With similar reasoning as above, we note that the algorithm has runtime $O(|i|^2)$.

So as you can see, the qualitative result does not change when considering the input length for *this* kind of algorithms, so it is often glossed over. When analysing e.g. [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) this is no longer valid, and you have to look more closely.

Comment: What does it mean by "$n \leq |i|$, $i$ the input"? Don't really get your $i$...

Comment: @wlnirvana: The input $i$ is some encoding of $n$ numbers. As the encoding length of each number is at least one, $n \leq |i|$ (the length of the input).

Comment: So once we take the encoding into consideration, it's not that accurate to say insertion sort is $O(n^2)$ because $n$ is not the input size. We'd better say it's $O(|i|^2)$. Am I correct on the point?

Comment: @wlnirvana: Technically, that is correct. I argue in my answer why it does not make much of a difference (here).

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for your clarification.